# LaTeX source code listing with less space between characters

Tags: spacing, listings

I want to write shell Code in my LaTeX document. I'm using the `listings` package, with a code sample adapted from [Tormod Fjeldskår](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741985/latex-source-code-listing-like-in-professional-books/742069#742069):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
   NETWORKING=YES

HOSTNAME= f e −19. l o c a l d o m a i n

}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that there is some extra space between every character when I generate a PDF. I would like the code without this space. The extra space is visible in the the part `HOSTNAME=`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21432/how-to-present-source-code-rdf-notation-3-in-latex

Comment: I would argue that this is not a duplicate, as the marked duplicate is asking about spaces between words, whereas this is referring to characters

Answer (score 20):

`columns=fullflexible` solved the problem.

By default, the spacing between characters is made uniform so as to preserve alignments. Setting `columns` to a non-default value restores the inter-character spacing (all characters are typeset at their natural width) but may break alignments.

For example:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[columns=fullflexible,caption=The Name]
dladm show-phys
\end{lstlisting}
```

Instead of `fullflexible`, you can use `flexible` or `space-flexible`, which try to preserve alignment by adjusting horizontal whitespace between words. For more information, see the section on the `columns` option in the [`listings` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (§2.10 “Fixed and flexible columns”).